Diophantine approximation by fractions whose numerator and denominator are both prime
Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be the set of all real numbers $x$
for which there are infinitely many pairs of prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that
$$
  \left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{q^2}.
$$
Do the following assertions hold?:

The set $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

The set $S$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

The set $S$ does not contain any algebraic numbers.


Remark: Without the requirement of primality of $p$ and $q$, the set $S$
would contain precisely the irrational numbers.

Numerical experimentation suggests that e.g. for the square root of 2, there is only a small finite number of pairs of primes which work, which is supported by heuristics.

I think that $S$ has Lebesgue measure 0. The numbers in $(-m, m)$ well approximated with denominator a fixed prime $q$ and numerator some prime have measure $ 2m\frac{1+o(1)}{q\log(qm)}$ by PNT. Since $\sum_{q \in P} \frac{1}{q\log(q)} < \infty$ by PNT, Borel-Cantelli finishes.

About $x = \sqrt{2}$: one has $|\sqrt{2}-\frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$ if and only if $|2q^2-p^2| < 2\sqrt{2}+(\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt{2})$, so for large $p,q$, the condition becomes $2q^2-p^2 \in {-2,-1,0,1,2}$, but $2q^2-p^2$ will be odd, so either $2q^2-p^2 = -1$ or $2q^2-p^2 = 1$. I think $2q^2-p^2 = -1$ can be ruled out: $2q^2 = (p-1)(p+1)$ implies $q \mid p-1$ or $q \mid p+1$, but $p \sim \sqrt{2}q$, so this is impossible. Maybe $2q^2-p^2 = 1$ can be ruled out by working over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

@mathworker21 For $x = \sqrt{2}$, one finds the solutions $(p,q) = (3,2)$,
$(p,q) = (7,5)$, $(p,q) = (41,29)$, $(p,q) = (63018038201,44560482149)$ and
$(p,q) = (19175002942688032928599,13558774610046711780701)$, and there is a chance
that these are all (if there are more, $p$ and $q$ have more than $1000$ decimal digits).

Mathworker21's idea gives an easy proof for $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$.  We have $|\varphi - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$ iff $|q^2+pq-p^2| < |\frac{p}{q}-\bar{\varphi}|$. Now when $q$ is large the fact the lefthand side is an odd integer implies $|q^2+pq-p^2| = 1$, so we must in fact satisfy the stronger $|\varphi - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{2q^2}$. By a theorem of Legendre's, $p/q$ is then a convergent of the continued fraction for $\varphi$, so $q,p$ are consecutive prime Fibonacci numbers. This only happens twice as $F_{n}|F_{2n}$ means $F_{2n}$ is not prime for $n>2$.

Actually, the fact $p,q$ are odd isn't needed to get $|q^2 + pq - q^2| = 1$, even with integer $p,q$ this form does not represent $\pm 2$.

$S$ is dense in $\mathbb R^+$. The point is that $$S_n=\bigcup_{p,q \in P; q > n} \left(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{1}{q^2},\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{q^2}\right)\setminus{\frac{p}{q}}$$ is open and dense for each $n$, since for large enough $q$ there is always a prime in $(aq,bq)$ for any fixed $b>a\ge 0$. Thus $S = \bigcap_n S_n$ is dense by the Baire Category theorem.
I think the third question is potentially hard, but heuristically I don't think any algebraic numbers should work.

@MatthewBolan Thank you very much! - Wouldn't you like to turn this into an answer? Besides, I also suspected the third question may be the hardest.

I will show $S$ is dense in $\mathbb R^+$ and $S$ is measure $0$.
Let $$I_{p,q} = \left(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{1}{q^2},\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{q^2}\right).$$
To see $S$ is dense, note that the open sets $$S_n = \bigcup_{\substack{q\in P \\ q > n}}\bigcup_{p \in P} I_{p,q}  $$
are dense, since for fixed $b > a \ge 0$ and any large enough $q$ there is always a prime in $(aq,bq)$ by the prime number theorem. Thus $S = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is dense by the Baire category theorem. Note that this would work with any exponent besides $2$, and even the analog of Liouville numbers will be dense.
To see $S$ is Lebesgue measure $0$, for $m>0$ write $$
S \cap [0,m) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{\substack{q\in P \\ q > n}} \bigcup_{\substack{p\in P \\ p < mq}} I_{p,q}.$$
Now $$\sum_{q \in P}\lambda\left(\bigcup_{\substack{p\in P \\ p < mq}} I_{p,q}\right) = 2m\sum_{q \in P}\frac{1+o(1)}{q\log{(mq)}} < \infty$$
as $\sum_{q \in P}\frac{1}{q\log{q}} < \infty$ (see here), so by the Borel-Cantelli lemma $\lambda(S \cap [0,m)) = 0$ and thus $\lambda(S)=0$.
